# The best approach to make a Document store on top of a Key/Value store?

Tags: c++, sql, node.js, database, nosql

There are some projects on GitHub which use a key/value store like `leveldb` and `rocksdb` to make a NoSQL/SQL store. For example [levelgraph](https://github.com/levelgraph/levelgraph) is a graph DB written in `Nodejs` and uses [leveldb](https://github.com/google/leveldb) under the hood. [YugaByte DB](https://github.com/YugaByte/yugabyte-db) is a distributed RDBMS on top of `rocksdb`. These projects specially `levelgraph` motivated me to make a `document store` on top of `rocksdb/leveldb`. Since i'm not familar with the algorithms, data structures and in general theory of DBs, I want to know what's the best approach to make an embeddable document store (I don't want it to be distributed right now).

Questions:

1. Is there any academic paper or reference on this subject? would you please list the required skills i need to obtain to finish the project?
2. `Levelgraph` is written in node.js using `levelup, wrapper for`abstract-leveldown`compliant stores. leveldown is pure C++ Node.js`leveldb`binding. If i want to program my DB in`Nodejs`using`levelup`, How much language difference will impact the DB performance?

Comment: Hey, I'm working on a similar thing using Rust. Did you find any reference on the subject?

Comment: @Belial Sadly I dropped the project long ago and I didn't find any valuable resource on the subject I'm not familiar with rust but if there is a reliable key/value store in rust then lucky you. You need a way to serialize your objects into keys and values then deserialize them back to objects. Then it comes the query language which you can build your own DSL (Domain specific language) or use  another language for scripting.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on that route right now, using rocksdb as a base. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Belial I'm also hoping to build a document store on top of `rocksdb` with rust. Did you find any resources on it?

Comment: @BrianShih I've read bunch of stuff and tried some implementation with NAPI over rocksdb, but didn't finish it. Made custom typed custom JSON structure and conversion between it, JSON and querying structure. Though, I didn't implement querying itself. If you are interested: https://github.com/yokunjon/brane